# How to implement PagingSource.getRefreshKey for cursor based pagination - Android Jetpack Paging 3

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-paging, android-paging-3

I am trying to implement cursor based pagination (based on [GraphQL Relay spec](https://relay.dev/graphql/connections.htm)) using [Android Paging Library 3](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/v3-overview), but I don't know how to implement [`getRefreshKey`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/paging/PagingSource#getrefreshkey).

This is what I've tried:

```
data class PagingKey(
    val before: String? = null,
    val after: String? = null,
)

class MoviePagingSource() : PagingSource<PagingKey, Movie>() {
    override suspend fun load(params: LoadParams<PagingKey>): LoadResult<PagingKey, Movie> {
        return try {
            val response = fetchMovies(
                before = params.key?.before,
                after = params.key?.after,
                pageSize = params.loadSize,
            )

            LoadResult.Page(
                data = response.edges.map { mapEdgeToMovie(it) },
                prevKey = if (response.pageInfo.hasPreviousPage) PagingKey(
                    before = response.pageInfo.startCursor
                ) else null,
                nextKey = if (response.pageInfo.hasNextPage) PagingKey(
                    after = response.pageInfo.endCursor
                ) else null,
            )
        } catch (exception: Exception) {
            LoadResult.Error(exception)
        }
    }

    override fun getRefreshKey(state: PagingState<PagingKey, Movie>): PagingKey? {
        // TODO: What to return here?
    }
}
```

In all the examples I could find a page number is simply incremented/decremented, but that doesn't work with cursors.

What is the proper way to implement this?

---

*Before this gets incorrectly marked as a duplicate, I've already seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66979100/4136777). This does not answer my question because their API is called as `service.getOrders(query, params.key ?: "", 10)` instead of the separate `before`/`after` arguments like `fetchMovies` above.*

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm with the same problem

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is get the index of the page to be reloaded and then go to the next page to get the `prevKey` or to the previous page to get the `nextKey`.

```
 override fun getRefreshKey(
    state: PagingState<PagingKey, Movie>,
): PagingKey? {
    return state.anchorPosition?.let { anchorPosition ->
        val anchorPageIndex = state.pages.indexOf(state.closestPageToPosition(anchorPosition))
        state.pages.getOrNull(anchorPageIndex + 1)?.prevKey ?: state.pages.getOrNull(anchorPageIndex - 1)?.nextKey
    }
}
```